# Reverse Engineering bios of ATM Machine

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, decompilation, firmware

I bought an Hyosung NH1500 off Offer-up and it boots up and initializes some peripherals and then spits out and error of "COM download is failed". I've searched Google and 0 results came up, I've been searching and reading everything I can about ATMs and reverse engineering them but there's not much information. I was able to find the ATM's update file and in the update file is a file called `boot.bin` and when I throw it into IDA Pro and set processor to ARM Little-Endian ARMv4T because the processor is an S3C2410A and that's what the datasheet said but I cannot figure out the address to load the binary at to get any disassembled code that looks correct, but inside that file is the string "COM download is failed".

So what I am asking is, can anyone help me find the loading address of `bios.bin` in the update file located [here](https://ufile.io/4xbb1).

Comment: Have a look at [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/294112252_Determining_image_base_of_firmware_for_ARM_devices_by_matching_literal_pools) perhaps the method can be applied to your MIPS device as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The files in the update are **not ARM** but classic 16-bit x86 code. For example, loading `bios.bin` at F000:0000 and starting disassembly from F000:FFF0 (standard x86 entrypoint) produces nice code:

```
cseg:FFF0                _reset:                            
cseg:FFF0                                                   
cseg:FFF0 FA                             cli
cseg:FFF1 BA A4 FF                       mov     dx, 0FFA4h
cseg:FFF4 B8 02 80                       mov     ax, 8002h
cseg:FFF7 EF                             out     dx, ax
cseg:FFF8 EA 20 00 00 F0                 jmp     far ptr loc_F000_20
```

The code is apparently hardware-specific and does not resemble much the classic BIOS of the generic PCs.