# How to load firmware x86 BIOS into IDA Pro 7.0

Tags: ida, firmware

I have a file called bios.bin which is the firmware of an ATM machine and I have found out it is x86 code 16-bit. But I don't understand how I'm supposed to set the base address in IDA Pro for an x86 processor.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19885/reverse-engineering-bios-of-atm-machine/19889#19889 says to load at F000:0000

Comment: Does IDA recognize this as BIOS image? If it does, it should pick the appropriate loader and it will do the job for you. It may be valuable information which IDA version you're actually using, by the way (free, pro) ...

Comment: @sudhackar I guess the issue isn't _where_ to load it but rather _how_ to accomplish this in IDA.

Answer (score 3):

You may use BOCHS x86 to emulate the 16 bit image and debug it using IDA pro. [image]

This is an example of bootloader of PETYA ransomware.

[image]